# Calendar for 24 solar terms of China

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

I am looking for a web-based calendar that has all 24 [solar terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term) (节气 jiéqì) of China and proper notifications.

There is a "Holidays in China" calendar in Google calendar, but it does not have all the solar terms. Is there any one that I can subscribe to?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/infinet/lunar-calendar uses Python 2.7 to generate an iCal file for the solar terms, as well as for the 农历. It is based on Hong Kong Observatory's conversion table, and can create events for the solar terms through 2100. It's not web-based, but you can easily import [iCal files into Google Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en).